# Pgbouncer - managing dynamic db settings

Tags: postgresql, pgbouncer

We are considering using pgbouncer for our project, which includes dynamic db creation (i.e each and every tenant that is added - a new db created)

As far as I understand, pgbouncer takes a config file that maps the databases.

The question is - is there a way adding new databases to pgbouncer without restarting it? (adding a new db row in the config.ini file)

Answer (score 4):

I was actually looking into this same issue.  It doesn't seem to be possible by default right now ([per this issue](https://github.com/pgbouncer/pgbouncer/issues/132)).  The originator of that issue has a [branch of his fork](https://github.com/mgjv/pgbouncer/tree/dynamic-pooling) for dynamic pooling, but it doesn't seem that will be merged. I wouldn't use it in production unless you're up to the additional work of maintaining a forked dependency for your project.

The current way is updating the .ini.  However, in addition to the overhead of maintaining configuration in another place this is further complicated because [based on the docs](https://pgbouncer.github.io/usage.html#command-line-switches) the "online restart" capability of pgbouncer only works for non-TLS connections and if your pgbouncer is running with unix sockets.  So depending on your system configuration online restarts for the potentially frequent updates might be out of the question.